# How to add Jquery accordion tabs from C#

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hi am new to J Query and in my project I want to implement J query Accordion from C# code behind  but i don't know how to add controls to jquery Accordion am using following code but this add controls to Accordion tab not to content

following code for aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion({
            heightStyle: "content"
        });
    });
</script>



 <div id="accordion" runat="server">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <h3>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Mobile_Name")%>
            </h3>
            <div>
                <p>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description")%>
                </p>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

Following code for .cs

```
TextBox txtEmail = new TextBox();
     txtEmail.ID = "txtEmail";



    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Mobile", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
    accordion.Controls.Add(txtEmail);
```

please tell me solution Thanks

Comment: So how far is it getting? What does the served HTML look like? What's working and what's not?

Comment: Are you using Jquery UI accordin?

Comment: 0% acceptance !!!!!!!!!! accept answers to increase it......

Answer (score 3):

If you want your txtEmail to be part of the accordion you have to use markup that is compatible with the accordion. Instead of only adding the textbox add the following:

```
// First add the header component
accordion.Controls.Add(new HtmlGenericControl("h3") { InnerText = "Email" });
// Then create the div for the accordion content
HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
// Add your textbox to the content div for the accordion
div.Controls.Add(txtEmail);
// Finally add the div to the accordion completing the accordion tab set
accordion.Controls.Add(div);
```

Note: Code is handwritten without compilation verification. If it doesn't compile let me know :)

Comment: Thanks alot for ur replay it's fine